# Can I run more than one ansible instance at the same time on the same machine?

Tags: ansible

To speed up deployment ,I decide to run more than one ansible instances at the same time on the same controller. For example , use one instance to deploy service A for all the targets. And use another instance to deploy service B for all the targets at the same time? Is it possible? Does ansible support this scenario?

I am trying ,and it seems work well ,but some times ansible's subprocess sshpass stuck forever. I don't know if it is caused by this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible is just a process running python like any other process so that in itself is not particularly a problem.

Your more relevant concern is if you are running multiple processes against the same target systems, are you introducing any resource contention. An obvious example would be yum/rpm installations being started by multiple connections that could cause you to wait for rpm locks... other similar scenarios will probably occur to you based on knowledge of what exactly you are doing in your ansible tasks.

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks for the explanation!